# How to use view_center_camera for fitting camera to 3D view?

Tags: python, scripting, 3d-view, camera

This function is supposedly the one for fitting the camera to 3D view with python(with mouse cursor hovering over the 3d view):

```
import bpy
for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
        if bpy.ops.view3d.view_center_camera.poll()
            bpy.ops.view3d.view_center_camera()
```

Hitting home keyboard-button activates view_center_camera function and does what it is supposed to, so the function seems correct and working.

It just doesn't work when I call the function from Python(like mentioned above). What is the correct way?

Comment: How do you call the function from Python? What is your actual code? Please edit your first post and add this piece.

Comment: And error message.. Educated guess: [You need to be in 3d view context](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6101/poll-failed-context-incorrect-example-bpy-ops-view3d-background-image-add)

Comment: You're not calling the function at all. A call needs parentheses, so `bpy.ops.view3d.view_center_camera()`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I can't seem to get my head around a solution doing it this way, however I found a solution for what I want to do here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16493/is-there-a-way-to-fit-the-viewport-to-the-current-field-of-view/16494#16494

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code works in 2.80:

```
import bpy

def find_3d_area():
    for area in bpy.context.window.screen.areas:
        if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
            return area

area = find_3d_area()
if area:
    override = {
        'area': area,
        'region': area.regions[0],
    }
    if bpy.ops.view3d.view_center_camera.poll(override):
        bpy.ops.view3d.view_center_camera(override)
```

Blender operators have optional parameter "context". In almost all cases, you don't need to override it, but this case is somewhat special.

In this case, you have to override `area` and `region`. I'm not able to explain into the deep why exactly these two keys are needed. It's only the result of my debugging inside C code of Blender, and trial/error in Python.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Thanks for the answer. Could you add a small description to your answer explaining what the code does or how it works?

Comment: typo line 14 btw.    needs at the end  :

Comment: thanks @spiraloid , fixed

Comment: this does not work for blender 3.2 and above where override object is deprecated. can you present a solution that works with version 3.5 using `with` statement and `temp_override`?