# How to make camera fit viewport in fullscreen mode?

Tags: python, scripting, camera

I'm trying to get my camera to fit the entire viewport ([`home`](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/8866/131649) button) in fullscreen mode
and this is what I've come up with so far:

```
import bpy

context = bpy.context.copy()
for area in bpy.context.window.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
        
        context['area'] = area
        bpy.ops.screen.screen_full_area(context, use_hide_panels=True)
        
        area.spaces[0].region_3d.view_perspective = 'CAMERA'
        bpy.ops.view3d.view_center_camera({'area': area})
```

but it keeps giving the error

> RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.view3d.view_center_camera.poll() failed, context is incorrect

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I forgot the proper region, this should do the trick:

```
import bpy

context = bpy.context.copy()

for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
        
        #sets into camera view
        area.spaces[0].region_3d.view_perspective = 'CAMERA'
        
        #sets to fullscreen
        context['area'] = area
        bpy.ops.screen.screen_full_area(context, use_hide_panels=True)
        
        #sets camera to fit viewoprt
        bpy.ops.view3d.view_center_camera({
            'area': bpy.context.screen.areas[0],
            'region': bpy.context.screen.areas[0].regions[0],
        })
        break
```

[reference answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/139438/131649) (please upvote their answer!)